# How to mask an image gray scale using numpy array slicing

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I need to replace 8 bits values (0 to 255) indexed set of an image (final image), following a "map values" from another image (second image) gray scale which related map indexes was chosen  from a primary image.

In fact this is  similar thing that MATLAB does with

```matlab
 indexS =  find(image1 == integer ('could be a integer from 1 to 255')) 
 imagfinal(indexS) = imagsecondary(indexS).
```

I tried following examples for python/matlab find()  on stack, for ex.: [MATLAB-style find() function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957470/matlab-style-find-function-in-python).  And the related ones...

I tried n.nonzero , np.argwhere and np.where, but I am really confuse.

I have three source images, let's say A, B, C, same shape, eg. (100x100) with diverse 0 to 255 values, I mean they are completely gray scales different each other.

So, 1st step - 
I need to get all indexes with values = 1 (but could be , 10, 196 , up to 255)  from A, so I did:

```py
Aboolean = np.equal(A,1)
```

result is

```
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],...
```

then I tried use those boolean index array results for getting the values from B:

```py
Bnew = B[Aboolean]
```

But it did not work for furthers steps, because the result is a map of values and the indexes are lost...

The values from Bnew are supposed to substitute the respective values 8-bits on C image,I mean those 8-bits values into the same position (or same indexes), remembering that B and C (also A) have the same shape/size array (100x100).

So I tried again:

```py
D = np.where(Aboolean,B,C)
```

when plotting the image, the final result is just the same image C !! No modifications, at all.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, figsize=(16,20))
ax.imshow(D, cmap='gray',interpolation='nearest')
```

results same image 'C'

My goal is a kind of replacing a set of values from B upon C (ruled by same index positions) , that was sliced following a map of indexes of conditions upon A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the boolean indexing from A to directly copy the values from C into B (if you don't want to modify the original B, first create a copy using `B.copy()`).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([0,0,1,0,0])
>>> B = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> C = np.array([10,9,8,7,6])
>>> B[A==1] = C[A==1]

>>> B
array([1, 2, 8, 4, 5])
```

EDIT:

C[A==1] = B[A==1]

Comment: Hi Tom, I mean copy values from B into C. But the logical seems clear now.

Comment: What about the non-zero values? The effect of avoiding non-zero values, as is done  by function find() in matlab. In python, would be :  C[ np.nonzero(cond) ] = B[ np.nonzero( cond ) ] ?

Comment: not sure I understand your question. what do you want to do with the non-zero values?

Comment: I am trying replicate the same logical, if I use matlabcode: find()...  Imagfinal(index) = Imag2(index). As explained in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388786/find-function-matlab-in-numpy-scipy?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Ah I see. `np.nonzero` filters the array down to non-zero elements, as opposed to creating an index of non-zero elements. What I think you want can be done the same way as the above solution: `C[A != 0] = B[A != 0]`

Comment: Ok! I did C[ np.nonzero(A==1) ] = B[ np.nonzero( A==1 ) ] and worked fine! I supposed as the same in MATLAB: ' index = find( A==1)', and then 'Imgfinal(index) = Imagsecund(index)'. Cool!!