# Converting a matlab script into python

Tags: matlab, numpy, python-3.4

I'm an undergrad at university particapting in a research credit with a professor, so this is pretty much an independent project for me.

I am converting a matlab script into a python (3.4) script for easier use on the rest of my project. The 'find' function is employed in the script, like so:

```
keyindx = find(summags>=cumthresh,1)
```

Keyindx would contain the location of the first value inside summag above cumthresh

So, as an example:

```
summags = [ 1 4 8 16 19]
cumthresh = 5
```

then keyindx would return with an index of 2, whose element corresponds to 8.

My question is, I am trying to find a similar function in python (I am also using numpy and can use whatever library I need) that will work the same way. I mean, coming from a background in C I know how to get everything I need, but I figure there's a better way to do this then just write some C style code.

So, any hints about where to look in the python docs and about finding useful functions in general?

Comment: Also, if you downvote me then could you please offer a reason? I'm not sure what about my question wasn't good...

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I suspect the reason is you don't show what you've tried nor give a small example array which demonstrates the behaviour. What does find do, what have you tried etc.

Comment: @AndyHayden I think it's reasonable to expect that anyone answering a question tagged "matlab" will know what the `find` function does!

Comment: Thanks Andy and Chris, I appreciate the feedback and have updated my question as well as fixed an error in what I thought find returned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB-style find() function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957470/matlab-style-find-function-in-python)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor well, you had to look it up in numpy, with an example it's immediately obvious for numpy folk what to look for - as well as being useful for others. This was mainly a general point of how to improve questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which the OP has done :)

Answer (score 2):

A quick search led me to the `argwhere` function which you can combine with `[0]` to get the first index satisfying your condition. For example,

```
>> import numpy as np
>> x = np.array(range(1,10))
>> np.argwhere(x > 5)[0]
array([5])
```

This isn't quite the same as saying

```
find(x > 5, 1)
```

in MATLAB, since the Python code will throw an `IndexError` if none of the values satisfy your condition (whereas MATLAB returns an empty array). However, you can catch this and deal with it appropriately, for example

```
try:
    ind = np.argwhere(x > 5)[0]
except IndexError:
    ind = np.array([1])
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.nonzero(x)` gives a tuple of the nonzero indices.  That value can then be used to index any array of the matching size.

```
In [1262]: x=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

In [1263]: ind=np.nonzero(x>3)

In [1264]: x[ind]
Out[1264]: array([4, 5])

In [1265]: ind
Out[1265]: (array([1, 1], dtype=int32), array([1, 2], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Still getting used to pythonic style, very new to it.  :)