# How could I translate the command find of MATLAB to Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab

I have this iteration in a program in Matlab and want to translate it to Python, but my problem is in the parameters for 'n' and 'direction'.

```matlab
for i=1:size(labels)
    idx_V=[idx_V;find(y(idxUnls(trial,:))==labels(i),l/length(labels),'first')]
end
```

Comment: What is the problem with these parameters?

Comment: I can't find a way to replicate them. A similar command I found was `numpy.argwhere()` but it doesn't consider those parameters.

Comment: What do those parameters mean? What is this code supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a one-to-one swap for MATLAB's `find` function in Python. Taking inspiration from [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957470/matlab-style-find-function-in-python), I would propose the following solution:

```
% MATLAB
inds = find(myarray == condition, n, 'first')
```

```
# Python
import numpy as np
inds = [ind for (ind, val) in np.ndenumerate(myarray == condition) if val]
inds = inds[0:n]
```

I'm sure there is probably some trickery to think about in terms of which dimension `find` operates over first, compared to `ndenumerate`. The Python expression could also be constructed as a generator.

If you want a similar implementation, you'll have to write it yourself in Python.

Comment: Also, `np.nditer` is probably the end-game if trying to implement maximum flexibility.